# ReacJS - Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: arrays, reactjs

*Hello everyone*,

I'm having a problem with my array, A well known problem but I cannot solve it :

*"Warning - Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop".*

I know that I need to give a unique key (the id of my product). I must probably have misplaced this key somehow.

Here the log :

[image]

And this my page "AccueilPage" (HomePage) :

[image]

And my Axios call to get all my product :

[image]

If I haven't given enough details to answer my question, please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: [Please see why we shouldn't post images of text :)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `produits` is an array that contains a single promise. Promises don't have an `id` property, so `key={produit.id}` is the same as `key={undefined}` which is probably ignored by React, hence the error. Or to put it differently: `produits` is _not_ an array of products.

Comment: Didn't know for the image @DaveNewton :S Thanks for the tip, I'll remember it

Comment: Hmm thanks for the explanation @FelixKling. I thought I was giving the key in a bad way ... but not that my key was "ignored" entirely.

Comment: @QuentinBlanche It's not ignored, it is `undefined` which is the same as passing no key at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should map throught `response.data` instead of `response`.

```js
 const [produits, setProduits] = React.useState([])

const onClickOrWhatever = () => {
getAllProduits().then(response => {
setProduits(response.data)
})
}


const produitAffiche = produits.map(produit => (
<ul key={produit.id}>
...
</ul>
</ul>))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to do like this :

```
const produitAffiche = produits.map((produit,index) => {
    return(
        <ul key={index}>
            (...)
        </ul>
    );
});
```

**EDIT : this way is not the best pratice for this. It's better to use a stable ID if possible instead of the loop index. Thanks *Dave Newton* and *srk* for your comments : https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys**

Comment: When items have a stable ID it's a best practice to use that ID rather than the loop index, event if this answer was correct (it isn't ;)

Comment: This is what I read online, if you can use a ID, it's better than a index

Comment: Agree this is bad practice. Source: ["When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort"](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). In this case, it seems the author does have a stable ID, so that should be used instead of index.